# Configuring the connection between client and server Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, configuration, oracle10g, installation

I've installed the oracle server and it's working properly. However, the client which is installed in another machine is not working. The error TNS-12541: TNS:there is no listener appears.

My TNSNames.ora:

```
SCP =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.2.39)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVICE_NAME = DatabaseIO)
)
)
```

In server machine I can connect to the databaseIO.

Are there other configurations to do?

Comment: Are the address and port correct - the `host` in the `tnsnames.ora` on the client is the address of the server, right? Is the listener configured (`listener.ora` on the server), using port 1521, and is it actually running? `lsnrctl status` should tell you if it is up.

Comment: The server address is 10.0.2.39 and it is using the port 1521. The listener status is ok, there is no error. In server machine I can connect the database using SQL Plus. Addictionally, the firewall is disabled.

Comment: You don't necessarily need the listener up to connect locally through SQL*Plus. `lsnrctl status` shows a TCP endpoint for `10.0.2.39:1521`? Can you add the output of that command to the question?

Comment: All oracle services are running.

Comment: Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(P
ORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER

Alias                   LISTENER
Version                    TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date              09-JUL-2013 13:57:40
Uptime         0 dias 1 hr. 42 min. 10 seg
Trace Level     off
Security              ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener parameter file    C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File    C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\log\listener.log

Comment: Listening Endpoints summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services summary...
Service "DatabaseIO" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "DatabaseIO", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...

Comment: That would have been better as an edit to the question. Anyway, it's listening on the private `localhost 127.0.0.1` address, not the external `10.0.2.39` address. You'll need to modify the config, with `netca` (or whatever the Windows equivalent is) or in the `listener.ora` file, so it listens to both addresses.

Comment: What's the function of sqlnet.ora in the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a comment you have an extract from `lsnrctl status`:

> ```
> Listening Endpoints summary...
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
> Services summary...
> ```

Your listener is only listening on `127.0.0.1`, so connections can only be made from the server. There is nothing listening on your external address `10.0.2.39`, so connections to port 1521 on that address fail.

Your `listener.ora` presumably has something either a single `ADDRESS`, or no `ADDRESS` at all, which will default to `localhost:1521`. You need to modify it to something like:

```
LISTENER =
...
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      ...
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.2.39)(PORT = 1521))
    )
```

or your machine's host name if that's resolvable to that address. Ideally this would be done through `netca` rather than by editing the file by hand.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  I've been looking all morning thinking I was fighting a firewall problem on a new install.