# Connecting to Oracle database installed on one pc to the java application from another machine

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle12c, tnsnames

I've installed Oracle 12c (desktop class) on my machine, and I can use it via sql developer on the same machine. Now how can I use the same database from another machine (for java application) in the LAN? I tried using the jdbc thin driver as follows: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.11.69:1521:orcl` where 10.0.11.69 is my ip address where Oracle is installed. Do i need to install any server where oracle is installed(10.0.11.69) to connect to my db from another machine?
  I'm trying this from past 3 days and referred to many questions of the same model but none solved my issue. 
My tnsnames.ora description is as follows:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to PDB if it is a Oracle 12c installation. You can add the following entry in tnsnames.ora:

```
   pdborcl =
      (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))
      (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVER = DEDICATED)
        (SERVICE_NAME = pdborcl)
      )
    )
```

After setting this, the listener needs to be restarted.

```
lsnrctl stop
lsnrctl start
```

Then the connect string will be something like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//10.0.11.69:1521/pdborcl
```

Note the connect string above uses service name instead of SID, because in 12C we need to use service name instead of SID to connect to PDB. Check this [post](https://community.oracle.com/message/12563638) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I did not added the pdb container when installing the database

Comment: anyhow I tried using the way you said and the result is same..`java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
`

Answer (score 0):

Java application will not use tnsnames.ora by it's own. You have to call:

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "..path to tnsnames.ora");
```

To tell the driver where to search for it. 
Also note, that some tnsnames.ora constructs are not supported by thin driver. For examples the "include" directive.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the following link, [Configuring the connection between client and server Oracle 10g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555281/configuring-the-connection-between-client-and-server-oracle-10g/17556231#17556231)

after researching for a long time I found that I need to add my LAN address(10.0.11.69) in the listener.ora file which solves my problem.

so my listener.ora will looks like this now:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST=
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.0.11.69)(PORT = 1521))

        )

    )
  )
```