# Oracle Error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener when I open connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, oracle12c

I have a webapp, VS2013, C# and ASP.NET, and I use Oracle 12c as DB, so when I try to connect to DB from my webapp I got this error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener, this is my code:

```
  public bool OpenConnection(Label lbl)
    {
        try
        {
            using (cn = new OracleConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistroConnection"].ToString()))
            {
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    cn.Open();
                }
            }                    
            return true;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nullExcept)
        {
            lbl.Text =  "Caught error: ." + nullExcept.ToString();
            return false;
        }
        catch (OracleException dbEx)
        {
            lbl.Text = "OraException - " + dbEx.Message;
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception current;
            current = ex;

            while (current != null)
            {
                current = current.InnerException;
            }

            lbl.Text = "Db base exception - " + ex.GetBaseException().ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I have the connectionstring on my webconfig:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="RegistroConnection"
connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =myServer)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = sidname)));User Id=user;Password=password;"
providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

the dll already added is:
- Oracle.DataAccess.Client

If I try to connect through Sql Developer I have a successful connection but on my webapp I have this error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Comment: Make a tiny Winform or Console app, run it from the SQLDeveloper directory and confirm if the connection string works. If it works then you know its something to do with FilePaths *like running an app from a directory that has brackets, eg C:\Program Files (x86)\..* If it doesn't work then double check your connection string... perhaps using a TNSNames.ora file with the TNSNames environment variable.. or seeing what SQLDeveloper has stored to connect to the database.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535842/connecting-to-oracle-database-installed-on-one-pc-to-the-java-application-from-a/28536545#28536545) on setting up connect string and connecting to PDB